# From where should we hit third party apis in django?

Tags: python, django, rest, api, structure

I'm a beginner in django. So my current structure is

```
--/project
----/settings.py
----/urls.py
----/wsgi.py
--/app1
----/migrations
----/admin.py
----/apps.py
----/models.py
--/app2
----/migrations
----/serializers.py
----/apps.py
----/urls.py
----/views.py
```

I want to know where and how (to access) should i code some things:

1. I want to connect with a third party storage service by hitting their apis and getting the data i need.
2. I want to store that data in my database in some model I created in models.py let's say 'Setting'
3. I want to generate some more data using Setting data and store it in database for another model let's say 'Item'
4. Finally the Item is what will be sent in the response for the rest api of my app which i have already achieved.

Right now I am hitting the third party apis inside my views.py like this:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ItemSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.order_by('order_id')

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Create a new Item"""
        # generate some auth string and hit api
        # http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        # response_auth = http.request(
        #     'GET',
        #     SOME_URL,
        #     headers={auth: auth_string},
        # )
        # print(response_auth.status)
        # print(response_auth.data)
        # auth_response = json.loads(response_auth.data.decode('utf8'))
        # print(auth_response)
        # serializer.save(user=self.request.user, name=auth_response['name'])
```

Also some other fields of Item i'm taking from the admin site. And some coming from the api.